# Получение доступа к TextBox на активной вкладке - C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем привет! Если коротко, то я делаю текстовый редактор с вкладками (чтобы на одной вкладке можно было работать с одним файлом, на другой - с другим). Есть код для добавления новых вкладок и генерирования на них новых TextBox

```
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(p);
TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
p.Controls.Add(textbox);
```

Но возникла проблема - я не знаю как получить доступ к textbox который находится в активной вкладке. Вот, например, так я получаю доступ к активной вкладке: tabControl1.SelectedTab, а как мне так до textbox добраться чтобы сохранять/печатать/очищать текст именно с textbox на активной вкладке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TextBox textbox = null;

TabPage p = tabControl1.SelectedTab;
foreach(Control c in p.Controls)
{
  if (c is TextBox)
  {
    textbox = (TextBox)c;
    break;
  }
} 

if (textbox != null)
{
  // found
}
```

Comment: Если не сложно, не могли бы Вы объяснить значение этой строчки:     textbox = (TextBox)c;

Comment: это приведение (конвертация, casting) типа - от `Control` к `TextBox`

Comment: Весь цикл лучше сразу заменить на `TextBox textbox = p.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: @andreycha, я начинающий и мне не очень понятен Ваш вариант кода `TextBox textbox = p.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault();` не могли бы Вы объяснить для меня чем этот код будет мне полезен? Спасибо.

Comment: @StepanKo если начинающий, то можете пока не обращать на это внимание. А так это более компактная и, на мой взгляд, более читабельная версия того же цикла.

Comment: @andreycha, значит Вашим кодом на одну строчку можно заменить весь код который предложил Igor? Или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: @StepanKo не весь, а только цикл.